# Finding Hidden/Disabled Element using Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to find button(Preview/Edit) on a webpage by using this code where it will click the button according to the argument text(buttonName).

The page behaves {when the page loads, it shows you 'edit' button. If you click edit then it shows 'preview' button and vice versa}

```
WebBrowserElement parentElement = waitForElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='serviceHeaderInner']"));
String s = parentElement.toString();
if (s.contains(buttonName) && (parentElement.waitForElement(By.xpath(".//a[.='" + buttonName + "']"))).isDisplayed()) {
    WebBrowserElement buttonElement = parentElement.waitForElement(By.xpath(".//a[.='" + buttonName + "']"));
    buttonElement.click();
} else {
    debugPrintln("        -> Invalid  buttonName '"+ buttonName +"'");
}
```

In the test case I'm trying to pass,

'Preview'

'Preview'

'Edit'

'Edit'

As when the page loads, there will be 'Edit' button and passing 'Preview' arguments twice in test case.. it goes directly to else and so on.Moreover passing 'Edit' argument also goes to the else portion. I guess there's something wrong with the "if" condition. But to make more dynamic "It should check for class which contains 'disabled' text acc. to the snapshots, so that this problem could be prevented at the first point.

Snapshots:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvtgZ.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44rqf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What value is assigned to s when you cast parentElement to string? Rather than doing
`.toString();`
I think you would need to do
`.getAttribute("value");` or `.getAttribute("text");`. or simply `.text;` 
We can change this if statement up a bit to work correctly. Do these buttons show up when the page loads or is there a wait period?
 Perhaps we can try this, let us not use parent element, as it seems to not be needed here. This can be refactored a bit more, but let's try it first:

```
if (findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + buttonName + "']"))).isDisplayed()) {
    WebBrowserElement buttonElement = findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + buttonName + "']"));
    buttonElement.click();
} else {
    debugPrintln("        -> Invalid  buttonName '"+ buttonName +"'");
}
```

Comment: That makes more sense.

Where is buttonName declared? In this instance, it would seem s will NEVER contain buttonName because it is just pointing to a div element and will not care about what is under it.

Comment: I'm trying to put a condition in if block whether the parentElement gets some text and trying to convert into string and find whether it contains the text as the buttonName is passed.

In Addition to that trying to find whether that button is displayed or not.

The buttonName is declared inside the if block.

Comment: I want to try a different approach to this, so I've included a few ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method below to click on the button based on name. Use `try{} catch(){}` on this method to handle the case when button is not present.

```
// button names can be one of [Edit, Preview]
// Provided you have only one button each on the name of Edit and Preview on your page
public void clickButtonBasedOnName(String buttonName) {
    waitForElement(By.linkText(buttonName)).click();
}
```